# Parsing /proc/maps?

Tags: c, file, parsing, process, proc

I wrote the following code in C. What I have done so far is open the proc directory and read the processes inside - dictories that did not consist of numerical characters were simply disregarded as I only want to look at the numeric directories. What I want to do is to print the PID of all the processes in the proc directory that have read and write permissions. My question is how can I extract the permissions of a process from the proc/.../maps file?

Here is a snippet of my code where I am having trouble:

```
sprintf(buf, "/proc/%d/maps", tgid->d_name); 
file = fopen(buf, "r");

while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {
    sscanf(buf, "%x-%x %4c %x %x:%x", &from, &to, flags, &offset, &major, &minor);
}

fclose(file);
if (flags[0] == 'r' && flags[1] == 'w') {
    printf("%d\n", tgid->d_name);
}
```

Comment: Maybe put your `printf()` inside the loop?

Comment: Even with the edit, the question remains unclear and shows a lot of confusion. A process don't have permissions (but it does have [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) ...)

Comment: Take several days to read more about Linux and operating systems. My answer gave some references (most of them are freely downloadable, but you need many days to read them). You stay very confused (a process don't have permissions!)

Answer (score 2):

> What I want to do is to print the PID of all the processes that are read and writable

A [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) is an abstraction provided by some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). It makes no sense to speak of a "readable" process (or a "writable" one), or one with "read" permissions or "write" permissions, since it is about [file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions). A process is not a file, and its `/proc/1234/` directory is just a *view* into that process given by the kernel. A process is using [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) to access files (and you might scan its `/proc/1234/fd/` directory).

The [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) file system is a pseudo file system specific to Linux. The `/proc/$pid/maps` is a textual *view* showing the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of a process. You can read that pseudo-file sequentially.

To change its virtual address space, a Linux process would use system calls like [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (which initializes a fresh virtual address space for a new program), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and `munmap`, [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), etc...

To scan a directory (such as `/proc/1234/fd/` or even `/proc/`) programmatically, use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) with `closedir` after having looped on [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) (you'll probably also use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on a file path that you have constructed) You could use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) in some cases.

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to get a broad view about OSes.

#### after edit

> What I want to do is to print the PID of all the processes in the proc directory that have read and write permissions

That has no sense. **A process don't have permissions**, but it does have **[credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)** (which define what file accesses are permitted to the process). You may parse `/proc/1234/status` to find the credentials of process of pid 1234 (in particular, the lines starting with `Uid:` and `Gid:` from that pseudo-file).

**Read some good Linux programming book**, perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/). Read also [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html), [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and also the failure cases of file related [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) such as [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), etc... (so also [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)). Take time to read *carefully*  [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

> My question is how can I extract the permissions of a process from the `/proc/.../maps`  file?

**You cannot** extract such information from that file. The `/proc/1234/maps` pseudo-file describes the virtual address space of process 1234. The credentials are given (with other status information) in `/proc/1234/status`. And it makes *no sense* to speak of the *permissions* of a process.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was I wanted to print the PIDs of processes that have read and write permissions

Comment: Read and write permissions on what file? thru what file descriptors?

Comment: I have edited my question which I hope will make what I am trying to do more clearer. I'm sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Even with the edits, you stay confused. You should read more about Linux programming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, but your program certainly doesn't do it.

Here's what your program does:

- Open `/proc/1234/maps` where 1234 is the process's own PID.
- Read the lines in this file one by one and parse them, recording the values in `flags` and other variables.
- Print out information based on the final value of `flags`, which was collected from the last (matching) line.

So:

- This will not “print the PID of all the processes” in any sense, since you're only looking at a single process.
- What is printed out is based on the last line of the `maps` file. On x86_64 at least, this is the [vsyscall area](https://lwn.net/Articles/446528/), which contains code and therefore is executable but not writable.

I won't offer a way to fix your program since I don't know what you want it to do. Saying “have read and write permissions” is incomplete: permissions over what?

Comment: I have edited my question which I hope will make what I am trying to do more clearer. I'm sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Even with the edit, the question is unclear and you (the OP) remain confused.

Comment: @user9042207 You're still asking about “the permissions of a process”, but not defining what you mean. If you're still having trouble, you should ask a new question where you *explain* what you want.